# Sorting arraylist with numbers in ascending form

Tags: java, sorting, collections, arraylist

```
al.add("1 Romeo and Juliet");
al.add("2 Juliet");
al.add("3 Romeo");
al.add("4 Mercutio");
al.add("5 Tybalt");
al.add("6 Nurse");
al.add("7 Robert Smith");
al.add("8 The Cure");
al.add("9 Suede");
al.add("10 Neil Codling");
```

I want to add al.add("11 Brett Anderson") on that arraylist, but everytime I do that, the output is always like this:

```
1 Romeo and Juliet
10 Neil Codling
11 Brett Anderson
2 Juliet
3 Romeo
4 Mercutio
5 Tybalt")
6 Nurse
7 Robert Smith
8 The Cure
9 Suede
```

what I want to happen is the numbers are should be in order, from 1 - 11.
what code should I put aside from Collections.sort(arrayname);?

Comment: Why not using a map or an array?

Comment: Use a treemap, the number as the key, the string as the value...

Answer (score 2):

You can create a class to handle this:

```
class Book {
   private int id;
   private String name;
   //other stuff
}
```

Then just add a new Book to your list:

```
al.add(new Book(1,"Romeo and Juliet"));
```

And just sort it using a custom comparator:

```
Collections.sort(al, new Comparator<Book>(){
        @Override
        public int compare(Book b1, Book b2) {
            return Integer.compare(b1.getId(), b2.getId());  
        }
};
```

---

Another way would be to use a `TreeMap<Integer, String>` where each id is mapped to one book name.

If you really want to continue with your current approach (which I don't recommend) you could `split` your `String` by whitespaces and take the first element in the array returned by `split` (which assumed that your `String` is always in the format (number whateverIsAfter)).

```
Collections.sort(al, new Comparator<String>(){
    @Override
    public int compare(String b1, String b2) {
         String s1 = b1.split("\\s+")[0];
         String s2 = b2.split("\\s+")[0];
         return Integer.valueOf(s1).compareTo(Integer.valueOf(s2)); 
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Collections.sort` with a proper `Comparator`

something like:

```
Collections.sort(ar, new Comparator<String>() {

        @Override
        public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return o1.compareTo(o2);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you use a `TreeSet` instead of `ArrayList`? The `TreeSet`'s structure sorts anything you put on it automatically. Also, create a class that takes the number and name separately and add those in your list instead. Don't forget to implement `Comparable` or a `Comparator`

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is you're sorting *alphabetically* right now, not *numerically*, so "11..." *does* come before "2...". You need to parse up until the first space character, extract that content into a number, then sort by that. This should of course check that "content before first space" *is* a number.

All of this might sound tricky, but by writing a new 'TitleNumberComparator' it shouldn't be too bad.

Learn about comparators, and comparable: http://javarevisited.blogspot.co.uk/2011/06/comparator-and-comparable-in-java.html

Answer (score 0):

you can use a Comparator passed as an argument to the Collections.sort(arrayname, compartor instance) to sort the ArrayList based on your criteria.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Map and keep as a key number and title as a value

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html

Answer (score 0):

Use a `java.util.TreeMap`, the number as the key, the string as the value. It will be sorted by the number "natural" order.